# How to execute something every 10 seconds?

Tags: java

I would like to execute a piece of code every 10 seconds. I have found an example on this forum, but have some issues with my implementation.

```
package robomow;

import robomow.SI7021;
import robomow.SGP30;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Environment {
  long delay = 10000;
  LoopTask task = new LoopTask();
  Timer timer = new Timer("TaskName");

  public void start() {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer("Environment");
    SI7021 si7021 = new SI7021();
    SGP30 sgp30 = new SGP30();
    Date executionDate = new Date();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, executionDate, delay);
  }

  private class LoopTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      System.out.printf("Humidity = %.0f  Temperature = %.2f \n", si7021.GetHumidity(), si7021.GetTemperature());
      System.out.printf("eCO2 = %d ppm TVOC = %d \n", sgp30.getECO2(), sgp30.getTVOC());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
  IOException,
  I2CFactory.UnsupportedBusNumberException {

    Environment EnvironmentTask = new Environment();
    SI7021 si7021 = new SI7021();
    SGP30 sgp30 = new SGP30();

    EnvironmentTask.start();

  }
}
```

I get this error, pointing to `si7021`:

```
Environment.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.printf("Humidity = %.0f  Temperature = %.2f \n", si7021.GetHumidity(), si7021.GetTemperature());
```

Comment: Java is type-sensitive. By convention, methods start with lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables you are declaring cannot be accessed inside the `TimerTask`; you should consider moving them inside the class.

```
    private class LoopTask extends TimerTask {
            SI7021 si7021;
            SGP30 sgp30;
            public LoopTask() {
                try {
                 si7021 = new SI7021();
                 sgp30 = new SGP30();
                } catch(Exception e){
                     //handle exception
                }
            }
            public void run() {
                    System.out.printf("Humidity = %.0f  Temperature = %.2f \n", si7021.GetHumidity(), si7021.GetTemperature());
                    System.out.printf("eCO2 = %d ppm TVOC = %d \n", sgp30.getECO2(), sgp30.getTVOC());
            }
    }
```

Comment: This was the first thing I have done, but it resulted in different errors: Environment.java:27: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown SI7021 si7021= new SI7021();....   and pointing to 'new'. Any idea why?

Comment: this time I got: Environment.java:32: error: unreported exception UnsupportedBusNumberException; must be caught or declared to be thrown si7021 = new SI7021(); and other 7 errors like before...

Comment: @bzc0fq I've updated my answer, but you should just directly catch all the thrown exceptions instead of a general `Exception`.

Comment: OK. I think I understand. I have updated the code with thrown exceptions and it compiles now and run fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bzc0fq No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by iota](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553205/642706) correctly solved your direct problem. But looking at the bigger picture, you are using obsolete classes. The modern approach with executor service and runnable is easier and simpler.

## Avoid the legacy classes

The `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes were supplanted with the executor service framework in Java 5 and later.

Likewise, the terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Replaced specifically by `java.time.Instant`.

## `Environment` class

Let's define your `Environment` class. This class monitors two pieces of equipment that sample the environment, and reports the current readings when asked via its `report` method.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Environment
{
    private SI7021 si7021 = new Environment.SI7021();
    private SGP30 sgp30 = new Environment.SGP30();

    public void report ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "------------|  Environment Report at " + Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) + "  |------------------------" );
        System.out.printf( "Humidity = %.0f  Temperature = %.2f \n" , si7021.getHumidity() , si7021.getTemperature() );
        System.out.printf( "eCO2 = %d ppm TVOC = %d \n" , sgp30.getECO2() , sgp30.getTVOC() );
    }

    class SI7021
    {
        public float getHumidity ( )
        {
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() * 100;
        }

        public float getTemperature ( )
        {
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() * 100;
        }
    }

    class SGP30
    {
        public int getECO2 ( )
        {
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 100 );
        }

        public int getTVOC ( )
        {
            return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 100 );
        }
    }
}
```

## `Runnable`

Define your task as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) object having a `run` method.

Using lambda syntax, that would simply be:

```java
Runnable task = ( ) -> environment.report() ;
```

Or use a method reference.

```java
Runnable task = environment :: report ;
```

Or, if you are not comfortable with the modern syntax, use an anonymous class.

```java
Runnable task = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {environment.report();}
};
```

## Scheduled executor service

The [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface repeatedly runs a task, a `Runnable`. You have a choice of `scheduleAtFixedRate​` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay`, so read the Javadoc to decide which kind of cadence fits your needs.

Be sure to gracefully shutdown your executor service. Otherwise, its backing thread pool may run indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️. We use a `try-finally` to make sure the executor service is shutdown. FYI, in the future  when [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) arrives, [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) will be [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). We will then be able to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax for simpler approach to do the shutdown.

```java
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting the scheduled executor service generating Environment reports. " + Instant.now() );
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = null;
        try
        {
            Environment environment = new Environment();
            scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            Runnable task = environment :: report ;
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                    task ,                                    // Implements `Runnable`.
                    0 ,                                       // Initial delay.
                    Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toSeconds() ,    // Period
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS )                        // Unit of time for both delay and period.
            ;
            // … do other stuff
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }  // Give our demo a chance to run a while.
            System.out.println( "INFO - Will shutdown the scheduled executor service generating Environment reports. " + Instant.now() );
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( Objects.nonNull( scheduledExecutorService ) ) { scheduledExecutorService.shutdown(); }
        }
    }
```

When run:

```
INFO - Starting the scheduled executor service generating Environment reports. 2021-01-04T07:46:54.494330Z
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:46:54Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 95  Temperature = 40.71 
eCO2 = 99 ppm TVOC = 1 
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:47:04Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 72  Temperature = 92.15 
eCO2 = 25 ppm TVOC = 42 
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:47:14Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 52  Temperature = 94.01 
eCO2 = 85 ppm TVOC = 89 
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:47:24Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 80  Temperature = 1.60 
eCO2 = 10 ppm TVOC = 78 
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:47:34Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 64  Temperature = 44.97 
eCO2 = 50 ppm TVOC = 40 
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:47:44Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 1  Temperature = 31.63 
eCO2 = 20 ppm TVOC = 69 
------------|  Environment Report at 2021-01-04T07:47:54Z  |------------------------
Humidity = 30  Temperature = 26.88 
eCO2 = 2 ppm TVOC = 86 
INFO - Will shutdown the scheduled executor service generating Environment reports. 2021-01-04T07:47:54.516543Z
```

In real work, surround the innards of your `Runnable` with a try-catch to catch any unexpected exceptions (and maybe errors). An exception/error bubbling all the way up to the scheduled executor service causes the service to halt silently, with no further executions performed.

Answer (score -1):

You need a class that extends TimerTask and override the public void run() method, which will be executed everytime you pass an instance of that class to timer.schedule() method.

```
class Hello extends TimerTask { 
 public void run() { 
 System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
 }  
}  
// And From your main() method or any other method 
 Timer timer = new Timer(); 
 timer.schedule(new Hello(), 0, 100000);//10 Min
```